# Adding appendices in toc using apa7 package

Tags: table-of-contents, appendix, apa7

I am using the `apa7` package and cannot get the "Appendix" entry in toc properly. I can't find a solution in the documentation. I tried some answers from other posts like using the `appendix` or `tocloft` packages but still don't get what I want.

I would like the TOC to show entries for the appendix sections. For now, it only shows entries for subsections whereas entries for the sections of the document (before `\appendix`) are shown properly.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{apa7}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[frenchpart=false]{french}
\title{My title}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \section{First section}
    Nice content.
    \section{Second section}
    Nice content again.
    
    \appendix
    \section{First appendix section}
    \subsection{First appendix subsection}
    \subsection{Second appendix subsection}
    \section{Second appendix section}
    \subsection{First appendix subsection}
    \subsection{Second appendix subsection}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:
[image: apa7 toc mwe]
If this is ok with APA standard, could you please help me to get there?

Ivan

Comment: You could manually add them. I am not familiar with APA standard. If template don't want them in the toc, you better leave them as it is.

Comment: just use `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\appendixname\space A}` after the `\section` command.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Tom. I accept egreg's answer since his code fits in the preamble and does not require change inside the document. But yours works fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mysterious reasons, the appendices are not added to the table of contents, but also `apa7` doesn't expect appendices to have subsections.

My advice is to avoid the class, unless one is required to use it for some submission: the typesetting choices are disputable (why aren't sections numbered?) and the code is awful. For instance the code for `\appendix` contains completely useless (and potentially harmful) instances of `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

You can patch `\appendix` so the appendix title is added to the table of contents.

```
\documentclass{apa7}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\setdefaultlanguage[frenchpart=false]{french}

%%% apa7 doesn't want to add appendix section titles in the toc
%%% let's make it do it
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\appendix}
  {\par}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\@currentlabelname}\par}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{My title}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{First section}
Nice content.

\section{Second section}
Nice content again.

\appendix

\section{First appendix section}

\subsection{First appendix subsection}

\subsection{Second appendix subsection}

\section{Second appendix section}

\subsection{First appendix subsection}

\subsection{Second appendix subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you egreg for your answer. It works fine. The APA recommendation is quite new to me but I feel like this package is following it properly (despite the poor code from what you said). For example, not using numbers for sections is [in there](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/paper-format/headings). Thanks again.